# API return PNG image with Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, guzzle

I'm sending an API request to Box.com to get the thumbnail of a PNG image. I'm using Laravel. When I'm using the following code I'm getting raw string data that I want to convert PNG image.

```
$client = new Client('https://api.box.com/{version}/files/{file_id}', [
            'version' => '2.0',
            'file_id' => $id,
            'request.options' => [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . self::getAccessToken(),
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        $request = $client->get('thumbnail.png?min_height=256&min_width=256');

        try {
            $response = $request->send();

            dd($response->getBody(true));
```

Without returning the `getBody()` method string I don't get anything as Box.com will be returned with the contents of the thumbnail in the body.

Here's the example string I'm getting:

```
b"""
‰PNG\r\n
\x1A\n
\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\r¨f\x00\x00\x00\x06bKGD\x00ÿ\x00ÿ\x00ÿ ½§“\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00H\x00FÉk>\x00\x00\x00\tvpAg\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00²gÜŠ\x00\x00€\x00IDATxÚÌýiŒ-[–ß‡ýö\x14Ã9™y3ï}ï¾©Þ«ªî®êê2%Ñ$[à \x19¶!Y&)\x1A”iC\x10`Ø0\x04I¶õÙ\x06,\x7F0­\x0F$a›0!Û0M‘¢\x04\x0E¦Dv³\x075ÙÕC©ç¡º»z¨ù½\x1AÞ|ç\x1CÎ‰ˆ=ùÃÚ\x11'ÎÉ“Ã}]2\x1C\x0Fùnæ\x19"vìØkí5ü×\x7F©Óó'\x19@)…RŠ˜\x13™ù‘Ñãoyçœ§ïí;²|ˆë\x0FÅö\x05óôÿ4~B©­qÌ?¹ýÕŒš>¿ÿÈ{Æ£”"ç<½7~\x7F¼¿Ý×wÏ“sFk½ýZÊ \x00\x12ÞwXcpÎñcÿäGøíßü5BPüþ—¾Ž±†\x14#\x19è;O×]\x00‰¾_ã½/3¤dš²"gEŒ\x11¥ÔtÍÍØË³È™\x10#Zk¬5[ã\x1AŸWJ2»Z),š@ÆÇPÆž¶î{3G\t­\r0*•ëRÖÆZGJi\x1A_y\x13­\x15ÖT\fÞ“‰h5Î—¡ª\x1CÚ\x18\x19óà‰1¢†\fYAUUÔuÍ0\f[ÏDk1\x1Ac\x1C9'B\x08TUÅb± gMí\x0Eù÷þÝÿ€ÿî\x7Fï_áÃ'ï¡ŒA;M&SåŒÒzöüT¹Ç²\Uùã†µôÿoÇî3»êÏÈ<Úýg‚\x14eRµ ÕÖE\x00RJ{\x05cç4Üb8EPæƒ“Co^$“IYm>ªæ\x0F-ï\x15ÎÛ>¼}“6\n
Õü~÷)»ËBRþVY\x16f\x1CÐ\x1A\x1E<xÈ_ùË\x7F™EÓÒwkÖë\x18#\x17\x17ç\x18c\x08>\x12Ä\x18I)\x10cœÎ•\x15¨œ\x01CJyKè'eE\x16¥“5Z+Œ¶“ ŒB©õ¶\n
•û1„\\x16~Ö@Þ{¯£°§,Š8\x15Á×J¡´"%EŒ‰œå»:Éx´QXeE¦væ\x162!\x04\x08ÊU4ÖÑ…\x04Q\x06\x14É\f\fh­EÉ”9ÙÜ‡(¥ñ\x08Á³^­iÛ\x03ž>{Äßø›ÿ1_{ó+üÅÿÉÿ”>\U¶Š”\x1Dz6wj:›h€<{Äó¹Ø}Ö7­¥›>£§g÷9n\x12þ}r2Wƒä”ÉãDŒS¢.\vÿøûø`æ\vr÷çºÁlÞß\x7Fù¡Pä4\x1A\x14£ÕPVnÙùwÏ?*©ÛŒgßw÷Ýëí\x1F@"\x13\x08¡çøø˜¿ÿ÷ÿ.¿÷{¿‹ÖŽÓ§kúÁ£µ,ê¾ï\x19\x06Oˆ‘˜â´ÐSJò\x13#1&RÊh}yÞ)S!ceë}™¢Ë\x16€R\n
cŒì¶Jì-­äûÆ˜ÉJ˜Ïáø¤2²ãÇl\x08I\x11"(•€@Îò“ˆ$\x15‰9àCOïûÙcV[\x16L\x08\x01¥ÀY+c\x18Ç]þ‹1N?ãx¼÷Ó=Ž–R\x08‘~è9;\x7FJU+\x1E?y‡ÿìïü'üÌg\x7F†E]ã»\x0E•6s²µ.ÆŸG<^c¾á]wÌç÷ÆÏd™z]~H\x19•òô÷üGM?Yþ¥<¶2WE;_«M6ãß|È&5\x7F°y:±Ñ\n
ãì¥\t™Ÿì;e\x1EM¦×l‚.\v\x14h}…rØ£¡çç¹Í1í¶;nÍüïq\x11ì;¯ì\x142“!\x052"Ø'GGü½¿÷Ÿó³?û9¾÷{¿Ÿ\x0F\x1F< ÷žÞwX+\x06X\x08\x1E­\fÞ\x0FÄ\x14\x10‹xŸÂºäô\žƒ¸3æÙï£ÐUUEJi\x12<Hh£ÐFîËÚ†¾ï'ÛwŒ»°Œ(Ã´\x13Ï,\x08-®KR\t2h¥‘Ó)òÌÚ\x00è‡\x01¯\x03É(bH"ú9@L$£Š|¦òyKJ‰aÐ8[Íž]$„HÎ‰õúŒÃ£CŽ\x0F\x0Fù+\x7FåÿÈK¯üUþù\x7Fñ¿Åã'OX.Ýf:)›Ëöln­Ÿ«\¿ùßÛ›ã~Ï÷*ËtRæ)m¹&›‘Ì­§2ð\x1D·y|?å<½µ»aoddöúÓ‹Çy\À(…¾”§›È»\x03Þ½»¼{C›kŒ\x0Fø*Óyòcaï.~ÝuPÛ\x13z\e\x05°ï3û\x1Eêh2ßÖ¯Úún\n
taÍÑbÉÃ\x07ïóïü;ÿK\x16Í]@\x11c “ñƒ‡œéûž¾\x1Fd×Lž\x10â4®4w\x03r"cQJO×\x11Aß\×\x1A‡RfÚ±Æç Ôæ>1Ôuµ–õz\rdb\x1CPJÏ”Ž™¬¹5tµ\v”PjÛ]J)cŒÞ|'\e(f<ˆ•1~?¥´eam”N\x002Î¹ò¹éœÉ8SSW\vbô(•È$BJhmq®¢®\x174®Á\x0Fž”áoüÍ¿Å\v/Üålý”¦YÈwrBa‹BS›e¦Š\x1D|ÅºÝ]só¿s¾z³š\x1Fzwy“E\x19Í]»\rgW!_z\x1ElÄä*¹Ø\x1AÃÎÝMÚcnY>\x00Ì\x17çü{»æøü³J)2Š´õ³çØØA“ðß4Žç\x19óüßçµnæ÷–RÂ\x02Ýê”ÿè/ý%â ‹»ëÖ¬V+Ö«5Cß³Z­\x08!L®À\èÈ\x19=úØåÖ·\x03•\x1A¥2"$QLp\x15ÑF¡t&\x13G\eqúŽµ\x16k\r©ëŠ¶mpÎaŒ#¥LUÕhm&!Ý§,÷í†9³ež‹{¡ËwÆu´\x11à]·qsÂm×M\\x05MŒ©Ä\x17Æµ‚\x04\x0EÕÜòbº×\x18Å\x12\x18úu·¢®\x1DëÕ\x05ÿç¿úWyvzŠVfR®JAVâjŒëJ+0*£È¨œP)A”ŸÑ\x1CÏyg=çòy\x10{b\fHÏ~¶ærßòÞ±<ækr\x1Eó¹ÊÍÈ;nëÍk¸Ä\x00òü\v{LÏ­‹ßF\x1AJ`nôÓ®\vœMç\x1FýÝ™ß¹{ì¾~\eÿþºÏìúúû”ÓíŽmí\x1F\x06ÏñCþÊ_ù?ñæW¿ÆA}‡¾ëI)•\x1D¿g\x18\x06Bð\fÃÀ0øi×œ+J¥ÔF‚Ô¾lÉÆnR\n
RÊ[Šd¾«j­‹°\eŒ1²àË÷mp¶Áššº^Hl`Çú\x19M~­õôžµ¶ü¾]PJQUM±Fdg\x7Fn\ WLãìy¥K\x01ÉyÌ#çqGTEð7ë'F\t¤\x06ßs~qÎ‹/ÞãÇ~ô\x1Fó\x0FÿÁ?äèè„uwQ\x02ŸvÚu·×Æ•ÃÛz\x06ã#Ú\x08½(\x10ÚñáE™èœÐÈç2iKñl6¶¼y>;\eÞMY·<›Ã›â\x169ƒV%\x12¨•BoìÅí%¶'ò\x7F­8Ì\x16Ý8˜]­µ+˜i.|W(šÍw/¿öQŽ}©¿yŠlþÞüõKãÊ±<#Mß_prÒð\x13?úÃüê/\x7Fžû/½N7x\x06?L»d\x08Pv©\x10\x02>xB\f¨Ùœ¥Q9•hù|wÜÝiE\x10M\x11‚0\tÿ˜\x01\x18?\eBÀûHJ\n
"""
```

Comment: What version of guzzle are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out myself using Guzzle3 on Laravel 5.1. Here's the relevant code which I hope you may find helpful in future:

In your model or if you prefer to use controller then it's fine:

```
/**
 * Get download link from Box.com
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return bool|int|string
 */
public static function getDownloadLink($id)
{
    $client = new Client('https://api.box.com/{version}/files/{file_id}', [
        'version' => '2.0',
        'file_id' => $id,
        'request.options' => [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . self::getAccessToken(),
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $request = $client->get('content');

    try {
        $response = $request->send();

        $result = $response->getEffectiveUrl();
    } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
        $result = $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();

        if ($result === 401) {
            self::regenerateAccessToken();

            return self::getDownloadLink($id);
        }
    }

    return count($result) ? $result : false;
}
```

In the above static method, I've sent a `GET` request to the Box.com API and the API returns with an `effectiveUrl` and that's the direct download file link we're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I got the success response for image as unique string values

```
$response = $this->client->request('GET', '/ap/generate-example/qr/image', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'user_name' => 'user_name',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'Authorization' => "Bearer assdadga",
                    'width' => '300',
                    'height' => '300',
                    'imgtype' => 'jpg'
                ],
                // 'sink' => '/uploads/images'
            ]);

$body = $response->getBody();
$base64 = base64_encode($body);
$mime = "image/jpeg";
$img = ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
dd($img);
```

Output:
`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/wAALCADcANwBAREA/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaE`

let's view this with
`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQA" />`